# Background video taking full height of site instead of container

Tags: html, css

Hello I have a div with a `<video>` tag in it, and this is set as the background of the div. I have it working but when I go on to create a div below that, the video extends into that div. Basically the video extends beyond its parent container into other divs. It looks like it is taking the full height of the site instead of the full height of the div.

Here is my code:

```
.banner {
    height: 903px;
    width: 100%;
}

.banner video {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -1;
    background: url() no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
<div class="banner">
    <video autoplay="" loop="">
         <source src="//myvid.mp4" type="video/mp4">
         <source src="//myvid.ogg" type="video/ogg">
     </video>
</div>
```

Does anyone know why it is doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change position:fixed to absolute and let the parent container be position:relative 
check this snippet

```css
.banner {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid green;
  position: relative;
}
.banner video {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background: url() no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <video width="400" controls>
    <source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
        Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
  </video>
</div>
<div>
  whkjshfdksjhdfksdf
</div>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks! this is the solution. cptnk beat you by just one minute with the same solution so I have to accept his answer. I gave you an upvote though!

Comment: Np totally fine...I liked his solution too

Answer (score 2):

You have `position: fixed` change that to absolute. Since fixed takes the current Display scope seperated from the parent elements. Thus scrolls and takes up everything since you used `widht: 100%; height: 100%;`

You might also add `position: relative;` to the banner class so the video has it as a parent.

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for. This worked for me. Thanks! Ill accept your answer when it allows me.

Comment: I think geeky has a better answer with a running code snippet and all you should probably accept that one just for future people running into the same problem.

Comment: for sure I will do that if you insist :D

Answer (score 1):

In addition to changes to defaults, there are changes to `position` of `.banner` (`relative`) and the video (`absolute`), and the height of the video has been modified to a percentage that maintains a 16:9 aspect ratio. To demonstrate that it covers only it's container(`.banner`), `.banner` is set at half the lengths of viewport. Please review the Snippet in Full page mode.

#### SNIPPET

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font: 400 16px/1.428 Verdana;
  color: #eee;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
}
.banner {
  position: relative;
  height: 28vh;
  width: 50vw;
}
.banner video {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 56.25%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 0;
  /*background: url() no-repeat;*/
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <video id="vid1" class="vid" src="http://html5demos.com/assets/dizzy.mp4" controls>
  </video>
</div>
```